# Wordpress styling extra margin

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site and I'm quite new to this framework.  There's some CSS on my page that's causing each "row of content" to have a 35px margin between it.  This appears to be in a css class called wpb_row in a js_composer.css file.  I'm not sure if this is some standard CSS class for Wordpress or if there's a global "have margin between each layer of content" setting.

Unfortunately I don't have 10 rep so I can't post an image of the page that's causing the issue but I can link to an image of where the issue is https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6wDr.jpg and the url for the site is http://am12.siteground.biz/~youbambu/ecorecycling/

What's the best way to override a CSS class within Wordpress from a standard point of view?  I've tried adding custom css to override this and remove the `margin-bottom: 35px;` in Appearence->Editor->Stylesheet.

Is it possible to either override this CSS in one global area?  I'm using a theme called Picasso in wordpress if that's any help, but I don't see how to override this CSS.

Comment: Site is very, very slow in FireFox but it is faster in Chrome. There are no indicators in Firefox. It's really slow.  .wpb_row {margin:0} add after all other css. That is not a "layer of content" it's a section. Having a margin between each section is a style choice, it's not default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overrride the css use `!important`. So adding the following to your stylesheet should remove the margin bottom:

```
.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid {
margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  Would you say it's standard to modify the stylesheet CSS?  Is there one specific place CSS should be edited as a standard?  (Other than Appearence->Editor->Stylesheet)

Comment: I would put it at the bottom of the stylesheet. Yes people would always modify the css. Since the css might be perfect for me, it mightn't be for you. There wouldn't really be a standard place to edit the css, but I would always do it in the stylesheet.css

Answer (score 1):

> > Is it possible to either override this CSS in one global area? I'm using a theme called >>Picasso in wordpress if that's any help, but I don't see how to override this CSS.

I would be careful editing/modifying there because I suspect you will lose these changes/modifications on theme updates (which Picasso auto updates).

The theme has a designated place located at Theme Options > Tools > Custom CSS. The adjustments you add here are loaded on every page, just like the stylesheet in editor. Furthermore, these changes are not cleared upon update.

Just my two cents, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this goal. This is not a WordPress standard or something.

1. you can edit js_composer.css and change what you want. OR
2. you can override this css rule adding a new role after js_composer.css loads. Something like:

   ```
   <style>

   .wpb_row { margin-bottom: 0px!important }

   </style>
   ```